# How to copy only visible text

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, webkit

If text is positioned off display, is there any way to convince browsers to copy text only visible on the screen when user selects text using ctrl-a or select all. In the example that follows, I don't want to copy text for the absolute positioned div.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:30;left:-300">This should not be copied</div>
    <div>Only this should be copied</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Some more information:

- Ideally I am looking for solution for webkit/gtk, but this applies to firefox/chrome as well. Both browsers exhibit same behavior.
- I don't control the page getting displayed. Page is displayed in webkit window for automated tool which tries to analyse contents of the page. Part of the algorithm looks at the text available by select all/copy
- I have access to full API webkit/gtk exposes.

Comment: I tried print to pdf feature of chrome on ubuntu. Generated PDF does not display positioned div. So there is something that knows exactly what is rendered, is available. Just need to figure which part of API supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do `display: none;` instead of moving it to the left?

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="display: none;">This should not be copied</div>
    <div>Only this should be copied</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I see no reason why you need to move it off the screen.

Comment: I think you missed bullet 2. I don't control the page. All I have is a url and webkit window that displays the page

Comment: I did miss that. My apologies.

Comment: Are you able to use javascript/jquery? You could use that to modify the style properties of that div.

Comment: Javascript, yes, jquery, I am assuming no. As I don't control the page, I don't want to inject full library for the page I don't control. But then I am guessing, if it can be done in js, it probably can be done using webkit API. Question is what should I be doing that limits the selection to displayed elements only.

Answer (score 0):

User can always use firebug to copy whatever they want.

Comment: I am not sure how this relates to my question. I am not preventing users to copy/paste. As stated in the question, I have a tool that is displaying the page. I want to get the text that is visible on the screen - effectively what user sees on the screen.